# Apple Pass not getting updated

Tags: push-notification, passkit, javapns, wallet

I am trying to update an apple pass by pushing notification.manual update is working fine. i tried to send notification using javapns. i am however confused about the payload. document says 'empty JSON dictionary for payload'.
Does that mean aps{} tag should be empty or the whole of it? 
Either way, I can't find any request in my access logs for getting serial numbers. every help is appreciated . Thanks.
EDIT:
 My basic question is that what should be the data that should be set to javapns library to trigger a apple pass update. i tried
    `PushNotificationPayload iosNativeMessage= PushNotificationPayload.fromJSON("{}");
PushedNotifications response = pnm.sendNotifications(iosNativeMessage, devices);`

This is not working. it is throwing an error inside javapns saying that it can't find 'aps'

`PushNotificationPayload iosNativeMessage= PushNotificationPayload.complex() ;
PushedNotifications response = pnm.sendNotifications(iosNativeMessage, devices);`

it is throwing error saying that payload is empty

FYI: I am using sandbox environment for testing

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Is there any code associated to this problem? If so, post it please. If not then maybe this isn't the right forum for the problem?

Comment: Hi Aleksander, please refer to above EDIT.